# How do I create this kind of a grid design for photos in a collectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I would like to create a collection view which takes photos and sizes them like below without looking stretched or squashed.

[image: Grid Layout]

I have tried changing the collectionView layout basing off fo this [Grid Layout Github](https://github.com/500px/greedo-layout-for-ios) but have not had much success in implementing it. I am using swift and found the code here to be close but not what I was aiming for as shown above.

Comment: If you want the layout be solely based on your photos' sizes, the result will never look as nice as what you have shown. Because there is a high possibility that the combination of photos' width will not be equal to the width of the collection view. Same with height. So if you want to implement something similar, you need to first define the boundary of how these photos are to be fit in, rather than how to fit in the photos to create a perfect boundary.

Comment: For example, if your collectionView's width is 300. But you have 3 photoes each with widht of 220 and height of 220... Now, how do I fit these 3 photoes into the collectionView to even remotely look like the design you have shown? pretty much no way. You will have a lot gaps in between

Comment: @programmingBeignner thank you so much for your detailed response I have been having some difficulty creating this design for a while. I see your point, how would you recommend going about implementing such a design without stretching or squishing the photos? I’ve seen Apple do it in their native photos app and  many do it online using just CSS and HTML. Thank you again for your response.

Comment: What I can suggest to you is to define the boundary first, like what I have said. So, you first decide 1. the maximum number of columns, 2 the minimum number of rows. In the design you have show, the max is most likely 3, and minimum 2. Then you decide the priority side, in this case, I would suggest letting width be the priority. This means, to fulfill the condition of fitting just nicely in collectionView's width is the first thing in your layout decision.

Comment: Then, you define a limit width... Let's say your collectionView's width is 300. So each row should be 100. This contirbutes to the max column of 3. But if your photo's width exceeds let's say 140, you make it a width of 200, so this row will only have a column of 2 (the min column number). Anything below 140, you scale the photo's size back to 100.. And you have, too, take the height into consideration, depending how neatly you want to place them horitzontally.

Comment: las thing I would like to say. The sample app you have been seeing, more or less has some photo resizing functionality involved to render a perfect grid layout as you have presented. So look into UIGraphicsImageRenderer. And, you should be creating a custom UICollectionViewLayout to do all these. After calculating images sizes, resize them, display them, remember to cache them and implement an effcient way of doing so. All the best